# How to multiply two randomly generated numbers until they equal 0?

Tags: python, while-loop

I need to generate 2 numbers at random in range -5 to 5, then multiply them until I get an iteration where the product is 0. Then print the amount of loops it took to get the result.

I have tried using `for` and `while` loops, and came up with this:

```
import random
num1 = random.randint(-5, 4)
num2 = random.randint(-5, 4)
print("Generated number 1: ", num1)
print("Generated number 2: ", num2)
product = num1 * num2
print("Product result: ", product)
while product != 0:
    print("Failed iteration")
else:
    print("Successful iteration")
```

The problem is that the code runs infinitely.

I am still very inexperienced in loops and would love if someone can help me find my error.

Comment: The `product` value never gets updated. You need to do your randomization inside the loop.

Comment: Stack Overflow has its own posting format/guidelines. Take the [tour]. If an answer helped you, you [upvote it and/or mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), instead of updating the post with the answer. Then, SO has a Q&A format, it's not a forum. If you have a new question, ask it as a **separate** question. 1 Q = 1 A. Don't edit the post to change the question, it would just make the existing answers confusing. You can link to this post instead on your new question to provide context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generate one pair of numbers, and the use that product to run your loop.  Since there is no way for the product to change, it's an infinite loop.  Try this:

```
import random

product = 10000  # Dummy value to get into the loop.

while product != 0:
    num1 = random.randint(-5, 4)
    num2 = random.randint(-5, 4)
    print("Generated number 1: ", num1)
    print("Generated number 2: ", num2)
    product = num1 * num2
    print("Product result: ", product)
    if product != 0:
        print("Failed iteration")

else:
    print("Successful iteration")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```py
import random

num1 = random.randint(-5, 4)
num2 = random.randint(-5, 4)
counter = 1

while num1 * num2: 
#while will iterate until the condition is not true, in python 0 is equivalent to false.
    num1 = random.randint(-5, 4)
    num2 = random.randint(-5, 4)
    counter += 1

print("Took this many iterations: ", counter)
```

Example without initializing `num1` and `num2`

```py
import random

counter = 1

while random.randint(-5, 4) * random.randint(-5, 4):
    counter += 1

print("Took this many iterations: ", counter)
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it necessary to define the ```num1``` and ```num2``` variables twice? Could you give me some insight on that part of your solution?

Comment: Sure! So I initialized them outside of the loop because I needed a statement that would be logically true for python to enter the while loop. I wanted the code to be readable but its not necessary to define `num1` or `num2` at all. I added a code example to my answer. The important part here is that the statement in the while loop will run before whats inside it so that why my counter start at 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you only calculated one "iteration" and stored its result in `product`. This will not change if you don't redo the calculation.

Basically, you need to put the calculation into the loop. You could use your original `while product != 0`, but then you'd have to calculate the first product outside the loop and further products inside the loop, leading to duplicated code. Therefore, I switched to an infinite loop (`while True`) , from where we `break` upon success.

```
import random

while True:
    num1 = random.randint(-5, 4)
    num2 = random.randint(-5, 4)
    print("Generated number 1: ", num1)
    print("Generated number 2: ", num2)
    product = num1 * num2
    print("Product result: ", product)

    if product == 0:
        print("Successful iteration")
        break
    else:
        print("Failed iteration")
```

Comment: This partly solves the questioners problem, but it does not "print the amount of loops it took." Whether or not the random numbers are "in range -5 to 5" is debatable. (You did greatly improve this answer by adding an explanation.)

Comment: Thank you! Do you mind telling me how I could use the ```enumerate``` function to count the number of loops in the code?

Comment: `enumerate` does something different. Here, I'd just run a counter as in @julian's answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately Im not allowed to use break nor continue but I think your answer will help me in understanding future code.

Answer (score 0):

`random.randint(a, b)` returns a random integer `N` such that `a <= N <= b`
`random.randrange(a, b)` returns a random integer `N` such that `a <= N < b`
Note the difference between `<` and `<=`

If you want numbers from the range -5 to 5 (inclusive) then you need...
`randint(-5, 5)`
 or
`randrange(-5, 6)`
but not
 `randint(-5, 4)`

The following code will accomplish your goal:

```
import random
iteration_number = 0
while True:
    iteration_number += 1
    num1 = random.randint(-5, 5)
    num2 = random.randint(-5, 5)
    print("Generated number 1: ", num1)
    print("Generated number 2: ", num2)
    product = num1 * num2
    print("Product result: ", product)
    if product == 0:
        break # exit the loop
print("We iterated", iteration_number, "times.")
```

Although the code above works, it is rather ugly. This is because it is once massive script, instead  not broken into separate functions. The code below accomplishes the same end result, but is easier to read, understand, and modify:

```
import random

def gen_once():
    """
    generate data once
    """
    num1 = random.randint(-5, 5)
    num2 = random.randint(-5, 5)
    return num1, num2

def test_once(num1, num2):
    if num1 * num2 == 0:
        return True
    return False

def gen_and_test_once():
    num1, num2 = gen_once()
    return test_once(num1, num2)

def gen_and_test_many():
    iteration_number = 0
    while True:
        iteration_number += 1
        test_result = gen_and_test_once()
        if product == 0:
            return iteration_number

iteration_count = gen_and_test_many()
print("We iterated", iteration_count, "times.")
```